# Make an Image with Radio Buttons a Block (CSS, HTML)

Tags: html, css, block

I want to make an image that has radio buttons responds like a block. When i change the scale of the window i want that image with the radio buttons change like a block without losing the positions of the radio buttons.

```
.island{

 background-image: url("nhsia.png"); 
 display:block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 550px;
 background-image: url("nhsia.png"); 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 }

 #radio1 {
 position:absolute;
 left:7%;
 top:17.5%;
 }

 #radio2 {
 position:absolute;
 left:15.5%;
 top:15%;
 } 



HTML

<div class="island">
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio5"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio6"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio7"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio8"/><br/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML?

Comment: i did it in the question

Comment: I'm not sure what you are really asking... Here is a fiddle of your current code https://jsfiddle.net/ztvef0zj/ . Just looks like  bunch of radio buttons. Perhaps post a pic of what you would like the end result to be.

Comment: i want this( each radio button one island) but without losing their position. Something like pinned there. here is the photo http://imgur.com/a/uOPNb

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the radio buttons are moving is because you're using relative values on the position of the radio buttons so when the parent element's size changes, the position changes as well.

If you don't want them to move around you should use exact values like `px` rather than relative values (as illustrated in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy6ptnmj/25/)).

#### CSS

```
.island {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/650x550");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#radio1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 10px;
}

#radio2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 90px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="island">
  <form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" />
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" />
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio5" />
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio6" />
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio7" />
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio8" />
    <br/>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

#### Additional Notes

So it looks like you're doing this for a map. I'd suggest that you make the image a fixed size as well otherwise the map would shrink and grow but your radio buttons won't adapt to the new position.

Comment: @ΓιώργοςΚαλογεράς Yes - instead of `width: 100%;` on the `.island` element, just make that a `px` width as well.